# What is the best place to start learning mobile application with j2me and good free ebooks for that?

Tags: java-me

I have not developed any mobile applicaiton so far. I am totall new person for this. I want to know what is the best place to start learning j2me. What is the best free books for that you have read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMHO, you really should use LWUIT to develop J2ME apps. Do a Google search for LWUIT. There's a few tutorials around (e.g. http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/javame/lwuit_intro/ ) and a reasonably active forum where you can get help.